# How does Tomcat7 work with JSTL? Jar file name is important?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am working on the old system which need to use JSP and JSTL. Our Tomcat version is 7.0.29. We are using Servlet 3.0 and JSTL 1.2.

There is a strange behave. I have download the **jstl-1.2.jar** and renamed the jar file to **jstl.jar** (*as our internal standard required*). Then put it into WEB-INF/lib folder. When I access my JSP page, I see below error:

```
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

But, when I renamed the **jstl.jar** back to **jstl-1.2.jar**, restart the Tomcat, then it works fine. For my understanding, the container will scan all jar files and find the tld files under META-INF folder. The jar file name should not impact the application.

Is there anyone know the reason?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `standard.jar` from JSTL 1.0 elsewhere? It isn't impossible if this way its hashcode ended up higher in the "unordered" (hash)set of JARs the container needs to parse.

Comment: I don't have the `standard.jar` in my classpath. I know it is strange behave, but it really happened.